# How to Configure Listview with more than 16 Items in GetView with holder

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-viewholder, getview

I have a problem with getView with adding items in ListView with BaseAdapter. When I store "0 to 15 items " like this " `if(position == 0 )` to `if(position == 15)` " it displays all the ListView items in sequence. When I try adding one more (16th) item to the ListView (like this `if(position == 16)`), it displays the first item in the ListView and doesn't show the 16th item which I have added to the array.

I am using a custom ListView row and each row has its own function which interacts with users. But I don't know how to add more than 16 items in getView using 'position'.

I have listview of 21 items but i can not implement its more than 16 items.

Any one have solution of this than pls tell me

**GetView Code**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder;
    TextView tv1;
    ImageView img;
    TextView desc;

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView == null){

     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screenlock_addapter, parent,false);
    holder = new Holder();

    if(position == 0 ){
    holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
    holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
    holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
    holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
    holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
    holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    if(position == 1 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

    if(position == 2 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        if(position == 3 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == 4 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == 5 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == 6 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == 7 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == 8 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == 9 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == 10 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == 11 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == 12 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == 13 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == 14 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

    if(position == 15 ){
            holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
            holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
            holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
            holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
            holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
            holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

       if(position == position + 1 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
       if(position == position + 2 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == position + 3 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == position + 4 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
    if(position == position + 5 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

    }
     else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: share your adapter code

Comment: i have tryied all but it display only 16 items ..i tried abov position +1 and every thing but it not worked

Comment: @Manish is  any solution for this...

Comment: show the getCount() method please

Comment: You need to optmise your code first. Use switch case. Always try to post clean code so people can understand. Show the place from where you are setting the data to adapter.

Comment: method is `@Override
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return Listitem.length;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code...

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder;
    TextView tv1;
    ImageView img;
    TextView desc;

```
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

if(convertView == null){

 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screenlock_addapter, parent,false);
 holder = new Holder();

if(position == 1 ){
    holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
    holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}

else{
    holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
    holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
    holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
    holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
    holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
    holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

}
 else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }


return convertView;
```

}

Comment: Not, Its still not working, its showing only 16 items (0 to 15). on 17th item it display first item..

Comment: first item should start with position of listview "0" but with your code its start position of listviw with "1". it display "0 " item on position 17th

Comment: if another solution is available than pls write.

Comment: By using your code , when i go to last row of listview and comback to first .. it change the position of row and display view in non sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
 MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

     if(convertView == null) {
     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screenlock_addapter, parent,false);
     mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
     convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
     } else {
     mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }

     mViewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
     mViewHolder.tvDesc  = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
      mViewHolder.ivIcon =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);

         mViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(Listitem[position]);
         mViewHolder.tvDesc.setText(desc1[position]);
         mViewHolder.ivIcon.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
         return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
         TextView tvTitle, tvDesc;
         ImageView ivIcon;
    }
```

Comment: Please just do not post your code.Try to explain a little as to what this piece of code does.

Comment: @Krishna patoliya  Your code is giving error"NullPointer ecxeption" and i have not anithing is null.. its pointing me on this .. `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screenlock_addapter, parent,false);`

Comment: any other solution for this ..??

Answer (score 0):

You only change the information if the position is 15 or less if you want to keep that way you should implement this :

```
if(position == 16 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
if(position == 17 ){
        holder.htv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_tv);
        holder.himg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_img);
        holder.hdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scl_desc);
        holder.htv.setText(Listitem[position]);
        holder.hdesc.setText(desc1[position]);
        holder.himg.setImageResource(aimg[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
```

...etc

**DANGER: THIS IS A VERY BAD PRACTICE, YOU SHOULDN'T DO THIS! YOU SHOULD DO THE WORK ONLY 1 TIME**

Comment: No i wont display 21 items in my listview.. 16 items already displayed but i want more 5 items to display after that 16 items.

Comment: @D4rWinNS any solution for this... how to add more than 16 items in listview ..?

Comment: i have tacken ther `return Listitemlength;` and is value is 21 but it is not problem problem is only 16 items can display. when 17th item come its tack first item from array not displaying 17th item from array  ...

Comment: That is normal with your code, In your code, you are only changing the information if the position is 15 or less, if you want to keep the way you are doing it ( it is bad way) just add until 21,  I edited the anwser

Comment: i try this all but it is not working. In my custom listview i want to create custom row with switch after 16th row but this code is not working so how can add that code for this row 17th and 18th. Now i have created sub sequence of my ListView and i am using only 16 rows in listview.

Answer (score 0):

this kind of problem occurs due height of list-view. Now the height of list-view's row is reduced and its work perfectly.